# What does UA mean?

Tags: terminology, marketing, analytics

When reading different articles about gamedev [**here**](https://blog.applovin.com/user-acquisition-best-practices-for-hyper-casual-games/) and [**here**](https://www.ironsrc.com/podcasts/whats-the-hype-with-hyper-casual-games-part-3-marketing/) I see the abbreaviation **UA**. What does **UA** mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means *user acquisition*.

It is generally used in the context of determining how you get people to pay for your service (or how do you get money from your users), and is often link to how much this costs.

Comment: I would add that UA is often _paying_ users to install your free game.

Comment: @Almo Not necessarily paying users. Mostly it’s just buying ads targeting your desired demographic, on Facebook for example. There are some platforms that direct some of that money back to the end user, for example in the form of rewards that come from the advertisement publisher’s platform (eg. “Download and play this other random game we have no affiliation with and we will give you 100 gold bars in our game!”). This tends to increase users acquired, but decrease longterm  retention.

Comment: "not necessarily" yes, which is why I said "is often". It's important that this is part of it since it's one of the most important methods in the mobile market.Companies pay _tons_ of money paying ad companies to generate installs.